# Convert SAS date to character inside macro

Tags: string, date, sas, sas-macro

I have a SAS date in date9 format that I want to convert to character variable with format yymmdd10. This works fine using put function (1), but when I instead use %sysfunc(putn()) - so I can use inside a macro - I get a completely different result (2).

eg. date = '01APR2020'd

Output:

(1) '2020-04-01' (character)

(2) 2015 (numeric)

```
%let date = '01APR2020'd;

%let want1 = put(&date.,yymmdd10.);

data test1;
want = &want1;
run;

%let want2 = %sysfunc(putn(&date.,yymmdd10.));

data test2;
get = &want2;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just look at the different SAS code that is generated by the two different uses.

The first one you are putting the code to call the PUT() function into the macro variable. So when you expand the macro variable to create SAS code you get:

```
want = put('01APR2020'd,yymmdd10.);
```

But in the second one you are putting a string in the style generated by the format YYMMDD into the macro variable.  So when you expand it to generate SAS code you  get:

```
get = 2020-04-01 ;
```

Which is just simple arithmetic and has nothing to do with dates or strings.

If you want to generate code that will make GET as a character string then add some quotes.  Either when you use the macro variable:

```
get = "&want2" ;
```

Or when you create it:

```
%let want2 = "%sysfunc(putn(&date.,yymmdd10.))";
```

So that you generate this SAS code

```
get = "2020-04-01" ;
```

Which will set GET to a character string with that YMD order date string.